# Is there a way to create React native Mobile app to support Portrait only while Tablet apps to support both Landscape and Portrait

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm trying to develop a react native app that will support only portrait layout in mobile and For tablets both portrait and landscape layouts are supported.

I have seen some info online that prevents android, ios in mobile and tablet from supporting either portrait and landscape, but I couldn't find a proper solution for my problem above.